# $_POST запрос

Tags: php

```
<form method=post>
    <input type="hidden" name=name value="<?= $_POST['name'] ?>">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

не понимаю что передаст атрибут value

Comment: В `value` попадет содержимое ячейки `$_POST['name']`, если оно не пустое и существует.

Comment: Ну вот нажал я на сабмит и что происходит дальше?
Про какое содержимое Вы написали??

Answer (score 2):

т.к. поле hidden, то в данном случае оно всегда будет пустым, если оно не заполняется на строне браузера каким-то скриптом.

Попробую рассказать, как это работает...

Судя по отсутствию на форме action, данные будут отправлены на ту же страницу. Поэтому получаем такой алгоритм:

1. Открываете страницу методом GET (ну т.е. ввели url страницы в адресную строку). Т.к. запрос GET, а не POST, в суперглобальном массиве `$_POST` никаких данных не будет. А раз вы пытаетесь получить отсутствующие данные, вы, вероятно, получите предупреждение об этом от PHP. В общем, при попытке вывести содержимое несуществующей переменной вы получите пустую строку.
2. Раз `$_POST['name']` у нас - пустая строка, value элемента будет пустым.
3. Допустим, поле не hidden, а text, либо у нас есть JS-код, который заполняет его данными
4. После нажатия на кнопку submit данные формы уже отправляются методом POST (т.к. у формы `method="POST"`), и на стороне сервера массив `$_POST` уже не будет пустым, а будет содержать данные из формы, т.е. `$_POST['name']` будет равен тому, что было введено в инпут.
5. Если при этом опять показать эту форму, то в этом скрытом поле мы получим то, что у нас было в `$_POST['name']`, т.е. то, что было введено перед отправкой этой формы.

Comment: спасибки за ответ

Comment: @hil400k, если ответ исчерпывающий, отметьте его "галочкой" ниже кнопок-лайков

Comment: @vanchester, "если ответ исчерпывающий, отметьте его..." - любимая фраза местных кармадрочеров. Не уподобляйтесь.

Comment: @Равнодушный, ок :)

Comment: @Равнодушный, А разве не в этом смысл вообще всего института overflow? В плане, сбор большого количества вопросов и корректных на них ответов - т.е. отмечать исчерпывающий ответ как исчерпывающий надо просто для того, чтобы люди знали, что проблема вопроса решена?

Answer (score 0):

По сути вы не чего не передаете(судя по коду, что вы предоставили). Это бессмысленная форма какая передает значение то, что содержится в массиве `$_POST['name']`, т.е тоже самое что передали ранее.